# Empty image when inserting inlineimage in Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a spreadsheet containing a chart, and I would like to add this chart as an image to a google Doc.
Everything seems to be going fine, but the image does not contain any visuals, it is just an empty shell. The size of it seems ok, I know this because I did a manual copy paste of the chart from the spreadsheet to the document and the size of the resulting image is the same.

The code I use is as follow:

```
var body = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody();
var start_offset = body.findText("##_CHART_01").getStartOffset();

var chart = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("charts").getCharts()[0].getAs("image/png");

body.findText("##_CHART_01").getElement().getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(start_offset, chart);
```

I have no idea why the image is empty, although it takes the space as if the image was there.

If anyone know, please enlighten me

Regards
Crouz

Comment: I have also tried to insert the image into the same sheet the chart comes from, and I get the same, an empty container. I am baffled by this and hope someone knows what could be wrong. I am on an enterprise account, could this be why?